# Product / patch installation or server upgrade required

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, patching

[image]Two environments both are having the same issue. Some basic updates were applied but nothing out of the ordinary. Now I'm getting two errors that I can't resolve.

> Product / patch installation or server upgrade required.
>
> One or more servers is not responding.
>
> Warning: The farm servers do not currently have the same product and patch level as each other. This page only shows the database status as
>   related to the product and patch level for the server that served this
>   page, and may not be correct for other farm servers until they have
>   the same set of required products and patches installed.

1. psconfig won't run because it says service pack 1 is missing from one server when it's not. It has been installed on all servers and if I try to install it again it says there is nothing to be updated.
2. all servers show there are no available updates.

It's the strangest issue and I really don't want to rebuild the farm.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is sharepoint version?

Comment: Enterprise 2013

Comment: did you type the command in the sharepoint pwoershell?

Comment: Yes I typed it into SharePoint 2013 Management Shell and ran as administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things you can do.

1. Run the Get-SpProduct -Local after that run the Config wizard. I would use this `psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force`
2. Clear the Config Cache on All server in Farm then run the psconfig wizard.

Comment: What is the best method in your opinion to clear the config cache on all servers?

Comment: two ways PowerShell or Manual. I used manual all the time. Stop timer server, delete the files and change the value of INI file to 1 then start timer service.

Comment: These steps have resolved the issue. I had to run it all twice and manually delete the files and change the ini file multiple times but it seems to have finally worked. Thanks so much for the help with this.